# How to top align a heading with an image (line-height issue)

Tags: html, css, styling

I have a 2 column layout, where in the left column is a heading, in the right column is an image. I want the heading and the image to be aligned at the top like this:

[image]

Now I achieved this by setting `h1 { line-height: 1em; }`. However, I also want it to work if the line-height is bigger, and if the heading wraps over more lines, like in this code sample:

```css
body {
max-width: 400px;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2em;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello world!
  <br>Foo Bar Baz</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/1c765c0d5963c84864bece62355713e0/tenor.gif?itemid=8240085">
</div>
```

I don't want to work with negative margins, because the left column will be filled with CMS content later. I can not control what element (h1-h6, p, etc) will show there and what line-height that element has.

Comment: You want image 2 to be aligned, how exactly? Against the right edge? Vertically? Horizontally?

Comment: The heading and the image should be vertically aligned

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusion, I meant I want the heading and the image to align at the top (see my updated question)

Comment: @Beppe line-height is too high... what's the idea behind it? have you tried to move `line-height: 2em;` (from `h1`) to the `div` rules?

Comment: Whoever downvoted answers, please upvote. The question was incorrectly stated (**completely**) making the answers wrong. The answers (at least mine) will be deleted afterward. Tnx.

Comment: Yes it was not their fault.

Comment: @wazz, well you said it `making the answers wrong` so if they are wrong they should be corrected or deleted, personnaly I just saw the quesiton and the answers has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Umm, that's what I just said.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the good old `vertical-align` property. It's always been a tricky property though.
In your case, for example, I had to make both divs `display` property `inline-block` as you need elements to be inline so you can vertically align them.
Also I had to put the closing tag of one `div` next to the opening of the next one, cause displaying them `inline` would render the new line in code as a space and thus making the second `div` fall to a new line.

```css
body {
max-width: 400px;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2em;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div >
      <h1>Hello world!
      <br>Foo Bar Baz</h1>
    </div><div class="leDiv">
      <img src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/1c765c0d5963c84864bece62355713e0/tenor.gif?itemid=8240085">
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a perfect time to use the `flexbox` layout in CSS.

With `flexbox` it's very easy to align content without having to set any specific heights—as you can let elements be the same height as their siblings.

I've created a quick demo with some minor changes to your code, I believe it creates the result you're hoping for:

```css
body {
max-width: 400px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2em;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
}
.flex-container {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <h1>Hello world!
  <br>Foo Bar Baz</h1>
  <img src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/1c765c0d5963c84864bece62355713e0/tenor.gif?itemid=8240085">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="flex-container">
  <h2>Hello world!
  <br>Foo Bar Baz Longer example with h2</h2>
  <img src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/1c765c0d5963c84864bece62355713e0/tenor.gif?itemid=8240085">
</div>
```

For more info on flexbox visit: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I didn't state my question clear enough: The heading and the image should align at the top (see my updated question). Flexbox unfortunately doesn't help here, since even with align-items: flex-start they don't appear aligned because of the line-height.